# How can I retrieve all Collaborators that are Directors on a specific Movie (Laravel + Eloquent)?

Tags: laravel, eloquent, many-to-many

I have 3 tables: `movies`, `movies_collaborators` and `movie_collaborator_types`.

A `movie` can have many `movie_collaborators` that can have many `movie_collaborator_types`.

How can I define and retrieve a collaborator that is a `Director` on a `Movie` on this type of relation?

It would be easy if it was a simple `Many to Many` relation, just creating a table `collaborator_movie` with `movie_id` and `collaborator_id` fields, but in this case I have another guy in the middle, the `collaborator_type` and I need to get and set this relation based on this field.

How can I define this relation?

Obs: I'm thinking about create a table `collaborator_movie` with `movie_id` and `collaborator_id` and `collaborator_type_id`. But I'm stuck there since it's the first time I make a `Many to Many` relation with 3 `fields` on the intermediate table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could constraint your results with a pivot condition:

```php
/** YourController.php */

$title = 'Inception'; // example of movie title
$type = 1 // assuming id=1 is for a 'director' type

$colaborators = Movie::where('title', $title) // searching the movie
                    ->first() // getting the movie object
                    ->collaborators() // calling the relationship
                    ->wherePivot('collaborator_type_id', $type) // filtering <---
                    ->get(); // getting the results
```

I haven't test it myself but this should work. Check [the documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many) regarding this aspect.

---

PS: If I'm not wrong, for this to work you should have this extra pivot column defined in your relationship model:

```php
/** Movie.php */

public function collaborators()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(Collaborator::class)->withPivot('collaborator_type_id');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried with HasManyThrough?

https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent-relationships#has-many-through

`public function colaborators() { 
     return $this->hasManyThrough('App\CollaboratorTypes', 'App\Collaborators'); 
 }`

Then maybe you can use:

`$colaborators = Movie::where('title', $title)->with('collaborators')->get();`

Comment: How can I define and retrieve a collaborator that is a Director on a Movie on this type of relation?

Comment: Your suggestion would work if my question was: How can I define and retrieve a collaborator that is a Director and is related to a Movie on this type of relation?

Comment: Obs: That is `director` on a `movie`, not `that` is `director` and has a relation with a `movie`.